# which one is better Solr Extension or Solr Plugin . I am a newbie , need the optimal choice , which is feasible in short time frame

Tags: solr, solr8.4.1

I am a newbie to Solr , our team is in the process of kind of extending an Solr Plugin which was already developed by other team , But for our usecase , we trying to Develop from scratch .
Can we go with making an Solr Plugin or Solr Extension , we chose Java Stack and are trying to enhance Solr for our Products Search purposes . Could you kindly share some of your expertise insights ,as we are bunch of experienced Java developers who are in this Solr Quest, Replies Appreciated ,
Thanks & Regards ,
GS.

Comment: You're writing a lot about everything else, except what actually is the purpose / need of your plugin / extension.

Comment: If you're a newbie, I would strongly recommend going with what you already have that has been developed and make the necessary adjustments. You'll have to expand and narrow down your question a lot for anyone to be able to give any useful answers; what's the difference between a plugin or an extension?

Comment: Hi , My Aim is to Search User data from the Insurance Silo of Data, My Insurance domain product should query the Indexed data within the Solr engine and make the query return holistic view of the Customer profile

Comment: Earlier Team tried to do DataDBImport handler where in they were able to import the My SQL Data using DataDBHandler task / job of Solr and then developed an plugin to run as a separate process id and let the plugin intercept the Solr REST calls by making their own REST Endpoints and implement the CrudRepositries and return Json Output which is then shown up in the Postman client / Solr velocty UI.Hope you could share your comments.